# On iOS, which view element is supposed to be like radio buttons?

Tags: ios, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best radio-button implementation for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847296/best-radio-button-implementation-for-ios)

I am looking at my storyboard and trying to make a radio button choice, but I do not see anything that is resembling radio buttons. Which ui element is meant to do that in ios?

I see the picker view, but I don't think this is equivalent to the radio buttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most commonly handled by using a grouped table view, and putting a checkmark next to the selected item.

For an example, open Settings app and go to General, then Auto-Lock. You are presented a list of choices; the selected one will have a checkmark. Tapping any of them will move the check.

You can do this fairly easily with a storyboard to set up a tableview, and a bit of custom code to toggle the checkmarks.