# How to make multiple radio group dynamically and manage check/uncheck state in a single view controller in iOS

Tags: ios

I have to create multiple dynamic radio group in iOS for my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best radio-button implementation for IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847296/best-radio-button-implementation-for-ios)

Comment: There are lots of example available, Check my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183518/usage-of-a-uiswitch/25183747#25183747

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create radio buttons and checkbox in swift (iOS)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117759/how-to-create-radio-buttons-and-checkbox-in-swift-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Preferred way to do it by Apple is using a UITableView with checkmark accessories. But if you need web style radio buttons, you can either implement yourself or use some open source libraries. 
Check this one: https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNRadioButtonGroup