# How to create NSRadioButton Group in Xcode 7 OSX

Tags: swift, cocoa, radio-button, xcode7

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82047/introduction-to-os-x-tutorial-core-controls-and-swift-part-2) on how to create radio button group. But it seems Radio Group is no longer available in the Xcode 7 library and I didn't find much information about it. How do I create something like this:

[image]

Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29117898/2976077) post can help you.

Comment: Thanks. But this requires 3rd party and it's also for iOS, not OS X...

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more careful when reading the introduction. It worked!

Comment: All answers do not cover the following change of behavior. In the past, I could bind some controller member to the NSMatrix (or radio-group) selection, and so have a value which is always synchronized with the selected radio button. Now I can't, since they're all individual buttons. I am forced to implement an Action (which I don't really need) for doing this (and for actual grouping of the buttons). How to go about that?

Answer (score 31):

Quoting from the [Xcode 7 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html):

> The template for Radio buttons in the Interface Builder object library is now implemented as individual NSButton objects, rather than the older NSMatrix, which is discouraged on OS X v10.8 and later. Radio buttons automatically act as a group (selecting one button will unselect all other related buttons) when they have the same superview and -action method. (16965941)

So drag individual radio buttons and make sure you connect them all to the same outlet!

Comment: I'm sure you mean same **action**, _not_ **outlet**?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yes, it works if you set it as **action**

Answer (score 11):

This way of doing radio button groups is "soft deprecated", follow what Xcode 7 says when selecting a radio button:

[image: Xcode 7 radio button]

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Eric's advice, I went back and placed the radio buttons in the same superview and it worked.  [image]