# How to make radio button with swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, radio-button, swift2

I am trying a lot of code and it's nothing is working for me. I need to make four radio buttons with swift when I show the question for the user to choose one of radio buttons.

Comment: does it have to look like a "regular" radio button or is it the functionality that is important?

Comment: well... this is what radio buttons "normally" look like: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/6d6fbe3aea745bcb8eac426c2bfe8d1e52ee6901/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6f6e65677261792f526164696f427574746f6e2d696f732f646174612f64656d6f2e676966 - do you need your control to look like this? or do you simply need four buttons with only one selected at a time?

Comment: It is nowadays **very easy** -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/77615047/294884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own login by using a mutabledictionary with button tag as key for dictionary. Add green/selected image for selcted button & set "yes" value for key (button tag) in dictionary for selected button & "no" value for other button's tag.

I have an [example](https://github.com/Gagan5278/TableItemSelection-Demo) for the same but in Objective -C

Comment: ok..just open the given url, a new git page will be open. Now little scroll down, or right hand side of the page you will get download button. Press download for downloading source code. Another option is cloning that can be done from terminal in Mac OSX. You can learn more from below links : https://gist.github.com/albatrocity/1201187  
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/siteground-git/clone-git-repository.htm
Let me know if you are facing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there's not a built in way to do this with Swift, but it's easy enough to code out. I'd personally recommend using this [Git project](https://github.com/shamasshahid/SSRadioButtonsController), as I've heard good things about it.

If you'd like to built a radio button from scratch, I'd suggest looking a making a check button by using a regular button with a `UIControlStateSelected` triggering a check img, and then set the `layer.cornerRadius` (after setting the `clipsToBounds = true` of course) of your button to half its width to produce a circle!

Answer (score -1):

The UIControl that offers the closest behavior from radio  button in swift iOS is the UISegmentedControl, take a look at the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html).

Here's [apple's guidelines for mobile controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html).

Some quotes from this article :

> Use a segmented control to offer choices that are closely related but mutually exclusive.
>
> A segmented control:
>
> - Consists of two or more segments whose widths are proportional, based on the total number of segments
> - Can display text or images

Comment: you mean I replace radio with segment put i need radio to show answer for user

Comment: You could use one UISegmentedControl with each segment containaing an answer as text,(if the text of each answer is not too long). If the text of each answer is too long maybe you can skin the control in order to fit to your need.

Comment: Still from the apple's article from my answer, why not use a picker in this case ?