# Radio button UI in Swift

Tags: swift, button

I want to create a UI that looks like this and allows the user to convert from one unit to various other units. I'm trying to understand what the code would be to create this one-to-many conversion relationship. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It's now very easy to do this .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77615047/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use two `UITableViews` side by side and set the **selection** to **single**.

Both `tableView`s can use the same source and **on any of** their `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you could simple calculate the conversion for the **selected rows** and update the `textField`s with the new value

You could simply make a **custom** `UITableViewCell` to recreate the appearance of the selection circle and update the image on the `tableViewCell`'s `setSelected` function

Comment: You could do that, but bear in mind radio buttons (ten years later!) are easy https://stackoverflow.com/a/77615047/294884