# add "delete all" button in edit mode of table view and display check box infront of each cell

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uitableview

I am making a table view and can display cells already.
My table view has a navigation bar with an "edit" button.

I am looking for a way to add a "delete all" button
and when this button is tapped, check boxes will display in front of every cell.

Could anyone guide me in swift 2.0?

Comment: Try doing it by yourself first. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117759/how-to-create-radio-buttons-and-checkbox-in-swift-ios) post.

Answer (score 0):

I can now solve my issue. By overriding below function, I can detect edit mode and display the button.

```
    override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if (editing) {
            super.setEditing(true, animated: true)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightBarButtonItem
        } else {
            super.setEditing(false, animated: true)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try checking this in git hub or stackoverflow exaples where you can change the table view edit style, where check boxes can be created

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

-(BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

if change in data is required for edit you might need to change the other delegates with below conditional check for an example

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if([tableView isEditing] == YES) {
return x_number;
}
return y_number;
}
```

If you are looking for delete all button in edit mode, then try creating a new UIViewController in seague where you create this check box and table view, when delete all button is clicked

Comment: Hello. The question is tagged "swift", please provide an answer in Swift, not in another language. Thanks!