# swift , add radio button Group to table view cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

how to create UI Table View Cell with radio Button Group Like facebook question post[image] in swift ??

Comment: You will have to create a Custom UITableViewCell

Comment: i create custom cell 
how to craete group of radio button in this cell ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117759/how-to-create-radio-buttons-and-checkbox-in-swift-ios

Comment: Very nice video about radio button cell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0owoXImGV4

Answer (score 2):

You should go with prototype cell, on selection of the cell you can change the properties/attributes of individual components in prototype cell as per your requirement.

Comment: i want to add group of radio buttons in custom table view cell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117759/how-to-create-radio-buttons-and-checkbox-in-swift-ios