# how to create single selection check box in swift2?

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

```
import UIKit

class CheckBox: UIButton {
    // Images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "check-sign.png")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "blank-square.png")! as UIImage

    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == self {
            isChecked = !isChecked
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to implement checkboxes in Swift 2. I was referring to [How to create radio buttons and checkbox in swift (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117759/how-to-create-radio-buttons-and-checkbox-in-swift-ios).

But my requirement is I want to implement single selection checkbox. I am not sure how to group the buttons via IB to make it single selectable.

[Any suggestion?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc81s.png)

Currently it is multiple selectable, I want to make it single selectable.

Comment: Hi, are you trying to use custom library? there are few options to create checkbox yourself, it could be using buttons and table view. Just keep the array status either selected or deselected

Comment: Many way are available but can i know where you want use checkbox like uitableview , uiview ?

Comment: I am not using any custom library. I have created own CheckBox control extending UIButton with Swift. But currently it is multiple selectable. I want to make it single selectable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with UITableView and custom cells ,and change tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = flase.

Ex : You can do that by setting the accessoryType on the selected UITableViewCell instances to UITableViewCelAccessoryCheckmark.

To deselect the row, set it back to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone.