# Make CheckBox in swift for IOS

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Is it possible to achieve this using `swift`?

[image]

I would like to make many checkboxes inside an `UIView` in `swift`

Comment: Have you run into a problem while trying to do that in Swift? If so, please describe the problem.

Comment: I dont know how i can do this @jjs

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you were talking about macOS (based on the screenshot) and not iOS. On iOS, checkboxes aren't trivial and your question makes perfect sense. My mistake.

Comment: Very easy today - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77615047/294884

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple just check for the image loaded on button and take appropriate action see below code:

```
// declare bool
var unchecked = true 

@IBAction func tick(sender: UIButton) {
    if unchecked {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"checked.png"), forControlState: .Normal)
        unchecked = false
    }
    else {
        sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"unchecked.png"), forControlState: .Normal)
        unchecked = true
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- You need to use two different images named as `checked` and `unchecked`.
- Then above code is used for separate button (checkmarks) you need to create.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add a UIButton on the board. Remove the text and add an image for a unselected(default) state and a selected state.

[image]

[image]

On the ViewController add an @IBAction for the function as follows:

```
@IBAction func check(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. make a `UI button`
2. set an `uncheckedImage` for your `button` for `UIControlStateNormal` and a `checkedImage` for your `UIControlStateSelected`.

Now on taps the button will change its `image` and alternate between `checked` and `unchecked` `image`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create simple checkbox control in swift like these...

```
 @IBAction func btn_box(sender: UIButton) {
    if (btn_box.selected == true)
    {
        btn_box.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "box"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            btn_box.selected = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btn_box.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "checkBox"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        btn_box.selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
 let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")! as UIImage
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")! as UIImage

@IBAction func tickavtion(_ sender: Any) {
    if unchecked {
        (sender as AnyObject).setImage(checkedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
        unchecked = false
    }
    else {
        (sender as AnyObject).setImage(uncheckedImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
        unchecked = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

which kind of checkbox you intend to make? Multi-selection or radio btn? Have you tried doing it in OC? I advice you 1) to add the btns into an array after you initialized them. 2) In the touch event you traverse the btns to implement your logic.

Comment: Multi-selection

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to create multiple checkboxes and set the x position.Set tag for each to identify when tap.