# Implement checkbox in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift3

I am trying to implement a checkbox in Swift. I used the answer of an other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117759/how-to-create-radio-buttons-and-checkbox-in-swift-ios) to get started. 
First I created a button in the storyboard and gave it the class checkbox. After that I, created the class checkbox. It is currently looking like that. I had do make some adjustments from the other post, because he was using a different version of swift.

```
    class checkbox: UIButton {

    //Images
   let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "selected")! as UIImage
   let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "rectangle")! as UIImage

    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, for: .normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if (sender == self) {
            if self.isChecked == true
            {
                self.isChecked = false
            }
            else
            {
                self.isChecked = true
            }
        }
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonClicked:")),for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

  }
```

But now, I always get the following error in the AppDelegate, when I click the checkbox.

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 3):

try this -

```
class CheckBoxButton: UIButton {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.setImage(UIImage(named:"selected"), for: .selected)
    self.setImage(UIImage(named:"rectangle"), for: .normal)
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBoxButton.buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.isSelected = !self.isSelected
 }

}
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Safest way to make check box:

Add a `UIButton` to `ViewController`

Add two images to Project: 1.checked.png, 2.un-checked.png

Set `checked` or `un-checked` image as button background or button image

Set button text to `""`

believe me, that libraries will make you confused.

Comment: But how can I select or unselect the checkbox then?

Comment: @fabioha In his example, you would just click on the button since you have already created images for when it is checked/unchecked.

Comment: So you would just change the picture whenever the button is clicked? Sounds simple.

Comment: @fabioha, yes make a toggle function that change the button image.

Answer (score 0):

I also recently had to make a checkbox and I used a cocoapod for that, instead of making my own. It lets you choose everything including colors, animations, shape and size! Maybe that helps:

[BEM CHECKBOX](https://cocoapods.org/pods/BEMCheckBox)

It really only takes 5 min to install and have it working on your app.