# How to give action for two radio buttons to make active one at a time?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here I had placed two radio buttons on view controller class but unable to give logic to make a radio button active at a time can anyone help me ?

```
@IBAction func radioButtonAction(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if sender.isSelected {
        workRadioButton.isSelected = false
    } else{

    }

}
@IBAction func WorkRadiobuttonAction(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if sender.isSelected {
        homeRadioButton.isSelected = false
    } else{

    }
}
```

Comment: Use DLRadioButton instead of KGRadioButton they will provide all things which you need. [DLRadioButton](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create radio buttons and checkbox in swift (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117759/how-to-create-radio-buttons-and-checkbox-in-swift-ios)

Comment: my question is different @ShamasS

Answer (score 0):

I am just using UIButton as radioButton.try like below

Create one array to store radio buttons

```
var radioButtonArray = [UIButton]()
```

Declare your radio buttons as UIButton or anyOther

```
@IBOutlet weak var radioButton1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var radioButton2: UIButton!
```

Append all buttons into array

```
 radioButtonArray.append(contentsOf: [radio1,radio2])
```

Set same target for all buttons

```
self.radioButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.folderRadioButtonClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
self.radioButton2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.folderRadioButtonClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

func folderRadioButtonClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {
    for i in 0..<self.radioButtonArray.count {
        if self.radioButtonArray[i] == sender{
            // here you can perform what you want
            self.radioButtonArray[i].setImage(UIImage(named: "checked.png"), for: UIControlState())
        }else {
            self.radioButtonArray[i].setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked.png"), for: UIControlState())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no already i used KGRadio button but unable to give logic for that

Comment: but where these buttons will be placed i.e how it will take the cgrect in view controller @DS Dharma

Comment: @Thiru i gave just logic only.i was placed in storyboard.