# Question about disabling one button when one button is active in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

The picture above has two buttons.
The background is filled in red with the left button pressed.

If I press right button here
I want the background of the right button to be filled with red, the left button to be white as the right button, and the button to be deactivated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bookTitleFilterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bookTitleFilterBtnClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        authorNameFilterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(authorNameFilterBtnClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

```
//left button
@objc func bookTitleFilterBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.isHighlighted == false {
                sender.backgroundColor = .red
                let title = NSAttributedString(string: "제목", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
                sender.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
                sender.isHighlighted = true
                self.isHighlighted = true
            } else {
                sender.backgroundColor = .white
                let title = NSAttributedString(string: "제목", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])
                sender.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
                sender.isHighlighted = false
                self.isHighlighted = false
            }
        }
    }

//right button
    @objc func authorNameFilterBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if self.isHighlighted == false {
                sender.isHighlighted = true
                let title = NSAttributedString(string: "작가", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
                sender.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
                sender.backgroundColor = .red
                self.isHighlighted = true
            } else {
                sender.isHighlighted = false
                self.isHighlighted = false
                let title = NSAttributedString(string: "작가", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])
                sender.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
                sender.backgroundColor = .white
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Hi, i post answer and also you can check this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117759/how-to-create-radio-buttons-and-checkbox-in-swift-ios It's help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to change the `backgroundColor` in the first condition of the first method. To prevent more of these kind of issues, try to define the logic in a function and call it anywhere you need instead of rewriting it over and over:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bookTitleFilterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    authorNameFilterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

var buttons: [UIButton] { return [bookTitleFilterBtn, authorNameFilterBtn] }

func updateButtonsAppearance(allButtons: [UIButton], selectedButton: UIButton) {
    for button in allButtons {
        let isSelected = button == selectedButton

        let currentTitle = button.currentTitle ?? "-"
        let title = NSAttributedString(string: currentTitle, attributes: [.foregroundColor: isSelected ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black])
        button.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .red : .white
        button.isHighlighted = isSelected
    }
}

@objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updateButtonsAppearance(allButtons: buttons, selectedButton: sender)
    }
}
```

Note that both buttons are now calling same function. So there is only one source of truth now. If it works somewhere, it works everywhere.

Comment: Oh no !! I just solved

```
let title = NSAttributedString(string: button.titleLabel?.text ?? "", attributes: [.foregroundColor: isSelected ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black])
            button.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Good! but use `currentTitle` instead of `titleLabel?.text`. It could be different on different states of the button.

Comment: Can I return a string value as the button is selected? I want to return "book_title" when the left button is selected and "author_name" when the right button is selected.

Comment: You can use ‘enum’ but comments is not goof place for discussing about issues. Feel free to ask a new question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing following line of code to change backgroundColor of another button. Add following line of code.

```
//left button
@objc func bookTitleFilterBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.isHighlighted == false {
            ....
            ....
            authorNameFilterBtn.backgroundColor = .white

        } else {

            ....
        }
    }
}

//right button
@objc func authorNameFilterBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        if self.isHighlighted == false {

            ....

            bookTitleFilterBtn.backgroundColor = .white
        } else {

            ....
        }
    }
}
```

This code will change color of buttons vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

set left button default selected from StoryBoard

```
var selectedButton:String = "" // gloable variable 

//left button
    @objc func bookTitleFilterBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if selectedButton != "제목"
        {
            selectedButton = "제목"
            sender.backgroundColor = .red
            let title = NSAttributedString(string: "제목", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])//title
            sender.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
            sender.isHighlighted = true
            self.isHighlighted = true

            authorNameFilterBtn.backgroundColor = .white
            let title1 = NSAttributedString(string: "작가", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])//title
            authorNameFilterBtn.setAttributedTitle(title1, for: .normal)
            authorNameFilterBtn.isHighlighted = false
            self.isHighlighted = false
        }
    }

    //right button
    @objc func authorNameFilterBtnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if selectedButton != "작가"
        {
            selectedButton = "작가"
            sender.isHighlighted = true
            let title = NSAttributedString(string: "작가", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])//Author
            sender.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
            sender.backgroundColor = .red
            self.isHighlighted = true

            bookTitleFilterBtn.isHighlighted = false
            self.isHighlighted = false
            let title1 = NSAttributedString(string: "제목", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])
            bookTitleFilterBtn.setAttributedTitle(title1, for: .normal)
            bookTitleFilterBtn.backgroundColor = .white

        }
```