# How to select one of three buttons in swift in an IBAction

Tags: swift, button

I have 30 buttons with 3 on each row.  I want the user to be able to select one of three per row, with the left column being default ("ee").  I can't seem to make this work...

With the following code I am able to change the color of buttons when they are clicked, but it doesn't deselect upon clicking another button. I want to send the button title string to the "ext" variable, which will tell the app which option the user selected on each row (each row has a different variable)

I am using this code for one row of 3 buttons:

```
@IBAction func `extension`(_ sender: UIButton) {
        ext = String(sender.titleLabel!.text ?? "ee")
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.09334511863, green: 0.1549694077, blue: 0.2597150259, alpha: 1)
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
```

Comment: You want a radio button behavior for each row. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29117898/13087977

Comment: Do I make a new array for each row? It seems like a lot of code would be required to make it work for this many buttons.  I was on a Swift course where they made an app with three buttons using an IBOutlet for each button.  I am trying to pick apart that code and see if I can make it work

Comment: For 30 Buttons you gonna need 30 Outlets. One way or the other you will need that. In the post i sent earlier he just groups 3 buttons and the logic is in the RadioButtonController. You need 10 arrays to do that, but you only code the logic once - which is great! Doing it straight forward with IBActions would cause a lot of duplicate/similar code.

Comment: Ill give it a go!  Im really new at this, still trying to wrap my head around how to put in these radio buttons..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding this to each row, starting with the button names

```
    aano.isSelected = false
    aama.isSelected = false
    aaye.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true
```

Comment: That surely works, the only problem is that this logic is duplicated for each button/row.